# babel-loader 6.0.0 doesn't work correct

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I am using *webpack* this is my

***webpack.config.js***

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  watch: true,
  watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 100
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: "babel-loader"
    }]
  }
}
```

and this my file from entry point

***app.js***

```
import React from 'react'
```

without anything, just simple line of code.
When i am trying to run webpack from command line and i got the next error

> app.js Line 1: Unexpected token You may need an appropriate loader to
>   handle this file type. | import React from 'react';

***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "a-b-c",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "react": "^0.14.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.0.14"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

Also, when i changed ES6 syntax in my app.js file to ES5 then it works well.
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also note that Babel 6.0 has a Note that says **Not all integrations have been updated yet. This is a very disruptive major so please bear with us as we smooth out the edges.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found out. The problem was with babel-loader and to fix this issue you need to install

```
npm install babel-loader babel-core babel-preset-es2015
```

and add to your webpack.config.js file next lines

```
loader: 'babel?presets[]=es2015'
```

[Source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-loader) of information

Thanks

Comment: Thank you. Was looking for it 2 hours :)